# Parsing error in over event tracking

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I try to set a roll over tracking event with gtmanager.
In GTM, i keep having a parsing  error , here the snippet

```
<script>
function mouseOver() {
document.getElementById("menu-item-75").innerText = mouseover(function(){
dataLayer.push({'event':'menuTopRo'});
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hi, thanks : Parse error. ',' expected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that dataLayer was initialized.

```
 dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
```